# Webpack - loader for mxClient, can't load all related objects cleanly in export

Tags: webpack, mxgraph

The current loader I have is :

```
{
    test: path.join(__dirname, '../libs/mxClient/js/mxClient.js'),
    loaders: [
        'exports?mxClient,mxGraph,mxGraphModel'
    ]
}
```

I seem to have to export each object that exists in mxClient in order to be able to use it in my application when i use:

```
var mxClientTest = require('mxClient');
```

Another question is that it seems that when i try to use import for my module, nothing gets loaded, but when i assign it to a variable and use require, i do get the exports that I specified in my loader, anyone would know why?

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to import it through webpack. You have to add the following code in the webpack configuration under module => rules

```
module: {
   rules: [
       ...

       {
         test: require.resolve('mxgraph/javascript/mxClient'),
         use: 'exports-loader?' +
      'mxClient,mxLog,mxObjectIdentity,mxDictionary,mxResources,mxEffects,mxUtils,mxConstants,mxEvent,mxClipboard,mxUrlConverter,mxVmlCanvas2D,mxStencilRegistry,' +
      'mxMarker,mxHierarchicalEdgeStyle,mxCellPath,mxPerimeter,mxEdgeStyle,mxStyleRegistry,mxCodecRegistry,mxGenericChangeCodec,mxStylesheetCodec,mxDefaultToolbarCodec,' +
      'mxGraph,mxRubberband,mxHierarchicalLayout,mxFastOrganicLayout,mxGraphModel,mxPanningHandler,mxKeyHandler,mxParallelEdgeLayout,mxLayoutManager,mxCompactTreeLayout,' +
      'mxPrintPreview,mxToolbar,mxOutline,mxCellTracker,mxCellOverlay,mxImage,mxLoadResources,mxPopupMenu,mxCylinder,mxRectangle,mxCellRenderer,mxVertexHandler,mxPoint,' +
      'mxHandle,mxRhombus, mxActor,mxArrow,mxArrowConnector,mxCloud,mxConnector,mxConnector,mxEllipse,mxHexagon,mxImageShape,mxLabel,mxLine,mxPolyline,mxMarker,mxRectangleShape,' +
      'mxShape,mxStencil,mxStencilRegistry,mxSwimlane,mxText,mxTriangle,mxAutoSaveManager,mxDivResizer,mxForm,mxGuide,mxImageBundle,mxImageExport,mxLog,mxMorphing,mxMouseEvent,' +
      'mxPanningManager,mxSvgCanvas2D,mxUndoableEdit,mxUndoManager,mxUrlConverter,mxWindow,mxXmlCanvas2D,mxXmlRequest,mxCellEditor,mxCellState,mxCellStatePreview,mxConnectionConstraint,' +
      'mxGraphSelectionModel,mxGraphView,mxMultiplicity,mxSwimlaneManager,mxTemporaryCellStates,mxGeometry,mxStackLayout,mxRadialTreeLayout,mxPartitionLayout,mxGraphLayout,' +
      'mxEdgeLabelLayout,mxCompositeLayout,mxCircleLayout,mxSwimlaneOrdering,mxMinimumCycleRemover,mxMedianHybridCrossingReduction,mxHierarchicalLayoutStage,mxCoordinateAssignment,' +
      'mxSwimlaneLayout,mxObjectCodec,mxGenericChangeCodec,mxTooltipHandler,mxSelectionCellsHandler,mxPopupMenuHandler,mxGraphHandler,mxElbowEdgeHandler,mxEdgeHandler,' +
      'mxConstraintHandler,mxConnectionHandler,mxCellMarker,mxCellHighlight,mxDefaultPopupMenu,mxDefaultKeyHandler,mxCodec,mxGraphHierarchyModel,mxGraphAbstractHierarchyCell,' +
      'mxGraphHierarchyEdge,mxGraphHierarchyNode,mxSwimlaneModel,mxEdgeSegmentHandler'
       }
        ]
}
```

then you import the vars in your code like this:

```
import {
   mxClient,
   mxUtils,
   mxConstants,
   ...
       } from 'mxgraph/javascript/mxClient'
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't know, f this is the best solution, but it helped me a lot to integrate mxgraph in reactjs. Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to use import instead of require when I use the following setup.

I use the export loader like so:

`{
  test: /mxClient\.js$/,
  loader: 'exports-loader?mxClient,mxGraph, mxGraphModel'
}`

And then when I import:

`import { mxGraph } from 'mxgraph/javascript/mxClient';`

or:

`import { mxGraph, mxClient, mxGraphModel } from 'mxgraph/javascript/mxClient';`